# Is it possible to enable ws-atomic transactions with Self Signed Certs?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

The question pretty much says it all.  I am attempting to enable ws-atomic transactions on a dev box with  self signed cert via:

```
WsatConfig.exe –network:enable –port:8443 –endpointCert:<machine|"Issuer\SubjectName"> -accountsCerts:<thumbprint|"Issuer\SubjectName"> -restart
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not use the SSL certificate because it does not support Key Encipherment or Digital Signature.
```

Is this possible or is there a work around for setting up ws_at that does not involve a real cert?

Answer (score 1):

Every created certificate has a "Key Usage" property which is also valid for your self signed one. You can start by making sure that your certificate has "Key Encipherment" or "Digital Signature" properties.

Assuming that you have the self signed certificate in your local machine store, you can check this as follows:

- Go to Programs -> Run
- Type mmc, press Enter -> Management Console will appear
- From "File" menu click "Add/Remove Snap In"
- Add "Certificates" to right
- Press "Ok"
- Now extend the related store locations and find your self signed certificate
- Double click your certificate and go to "Details" tab.
- Find the "Key Usage" property.

So if you dont have "Key Encipherment" or "Digital Signature" properties in your self signed certificate, you can simply create another one that has these properties.

Comment: Than you for your reply.  Properties indicate that both features are available, however, our admin is telling me self signed certs will not provide these features.